# Help creating a new theme based on Adwaita?

Tags: gnome, themes, css

I'd like to create a theme based on Adwaita.

I discovered that Adwaita no longer uses `*.css` files:

```
cat /usr/share/themes/Adwaita/gtk-3.0/gtk.css
/* Adwaita is now part of GTK+ 3, this file is no longer used */
```

I found the Adwaita source code on GitLab:

MASTER:
https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/tree/master/gtk/theme/Adwaita

VERSION 3.24.10:
https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/tree/3.24.10/gtk/theme/Adwaita

(UPDATE: The "master" branch on GitLab may be "buggy" since it is in development. Instead, a more stable branch such as 3.24.10 should be used).

Therefore, I can download the source files from Gitlab and modify the included `*.scss` files with the color changes I want.

Once I've made my changes, how do compile the source into a new theme, and deploy it on my machine?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***Ubuntu 18.04***

I Just tried it by understanding the `README` file from `~/Downloads/gtk-master/gtk/theme/Adwaita/` from the link you provided.. https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/tree/master/gtk/theme/Adwaita

1. Have downloaded the source code zip file..

[image]

2. edited some colors (just to try) in the file `~/Downloads/gtk-master/gtk/theme/Adwaita/_colors.scss`

Content:

```
$base_color: if($variant == 'light', #00FF00, lighten(desaturate(#241f31, 100%), 2%));
$text_color: if($variant == 'light', black, white);
$bg_color: if($variant == 'light', #0000FF, darken(desaturate(#3d3846, 100%), 4%));
$fg_color: if($variant == 'light', #2e3436, #eeeeec);

$selected_fg_color: #FF0000;
```

[image]

3. Saved & Closed
4. `sudo apt install sassc`
5. `cd ~/Downloads/gtk-master/gtk/theme/Adwaita`
6. `sassc -M -t compact gtk-contained.scss MyCustomized.css`
7. copied this MyCustomized.css file into a newly created theme folder in `/usr/share/themes/MyCustomized/gtk-3.0/` and renamed it as `gtk.css`
8. copied the `assets` folder from `~/Downloads/gtk-master/gtk/theme/Adwaita/` to `/usr/share/themes/MyCustomized/gtk-3.0/`
9. this MyCustomized theme can be selected from `gnome-tweaks`

and the result is

[image]

Comment: Pratap, this is a very clear answer, and it works to some extent... However, I think the assets are not generated. For example, after I follow your instructions, the check-mark and radio-button-dot images are missing inside check boxes and radio buttons. To see what I mean, try opening the Screenshot application after you've selected your custom theme, and notice that the selected check-boxes or selected radio-buttons are rendered as red squares. Is there another step that is needed to produce the corresponding assets?

Comment: One more question, how is the corresponding `/usr/share/gnome-shell/gnome-shell-theme.gresource` file generated from the custom theme files? (Is it simply a matter of running `glib-compile-resources` on ALL files in the `...gtk/theme/Adwaita` directory downloaded from GitLab?)

Comment: Pratap, interestingly, my `/usr/share/themes/Adwaita/gtk-3.0` doesn't have an `assets` sub-directory. (I also have a `/usr/share/themes/Default` directory, which also does not have an `assets` sub-directory). Nevertheless, I've copied the the `assets` directory from the source code into my new `...gtk-3.0` directory, as you suggested, and it worked. Please add this after step 7 in your answer so it helps others, as well.

Comment: I noticed that getting the source from the "master"  branch on GitLab produced a theme with visual "quirks", as you described. Then I used version "3.24.10" from GitLab ( https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/tree/3.24.10/gtk/theme/Adwaita). This version is a closer match to GTK version 3.24.8, that is currently installed in Ubuntu 19.04, and doesn't have the visual "quirks". I guess the "master" branch is "beading edge" and will probably be buggy.