# Home folder icons are black-and-white symbolic icons with the Adwaita icon theme

Tags: gnome, icons

How can I get the standard *colored* Gnome Adwaita folder icons when I select the *Adwaita* icon theme?

When I select *Adwaita (default)* as my icon set in GnomeTweaks, all of the icons displayed in Nautilus in my home folder are black-and-white symbolic icons.

I reinstalled the *adwaita-icon-theme* package, but this did not solve the problem.

There is only one *places* folder inside my Adwaita icon theme.

```
find /usr/share/icons/Adwaita -name places
/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/scalable/places
```

I looked in */usr/share/icons/Adwaita/scalable/places*, and I see the same black-and-white symbolic icons:

```
ls -1 /usr/share/icons/Adwaita/scalable/places
folder-documents-symbolic.svg
folder-download-symbolic.svg
folder-music-symbolic.svg
folder-pictures-symbolic.svg
folder-publicshare-symbolic.svg
folder-remote-symbolic.svg
folder-saved-search-symbolic.svg
folder-symbolic.svg
folder-templates-symbolic.svg
folder-videos-symbolic.svg
network-server-symbolic.svg
network-workgroup-symbolic.svg
start-here-symbolic.svg
user-bookmarks-symbolic.svg
user-desktop-symbolic.svg
user-home-symbolic.svg
user-trash-symbolic.svg
```

(I am using Ubuntu 19.04, and I have the gnome-session package installed).

Here is a screenshot of my home folder:

[image: Screenshot of home folder showing black-and-white symbolic folder icons]

Comment: Is this on the same system mentioned in https://askubuntu.com/questions/1170151/help-creating-a-new-theme-based-on-adwaita?

Comment: DK Bose, not quite... The physical system is the same, but I had performed testing related to the other question in a virtual machine. The icon issue in this question is not related to that question.

Comment: I installed `vanilla-gnome-desktop` and the `/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/` folder now has multiple sub-folders, such as `16x16`, `32x32`, `48x48`, etc. Inside these are colored folder icons. Then, if I select *Adwaita (default)* as the icon theme in Gnome Tweaks, I can see colored "home" folders in Nautilus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try installing the `adwaita-icon-theme-full` package using the following command:

```
sudo apt install adwaita-icon-theme-full
```